# what is the function name in java clear the screen in the cmd 

Tags: java, function, flush

some string show in the cmd flush  one time ,

i cant see the  details  , so  i have to find the  function that which flush the  cmd ,

so  what is the funciton  ?  i want to remove it ,

thanks

this is the code :

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
String reid = exec.submit(new SendMsg(sm)).toString();
```

Comment: Your code has no relation at all to the question.

Comment: I can't understand this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "function" for this.  Not in the standard Java console.  You can call a bunch of println's though to scroll the text off of the screen if you so desire. Either that or use a 3rd party console or create a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You're making the mistaken assumption that your process owns the console and can write anything it likes on it and it'll stay in place.
This is not the case. The console is shared with all other processes running in it, and each can write to it at will.

That's why there's no command to clear the console, it's not yours to clear.

Comment: No. In general, any process can clear the console. It's just that Java doesn't expose this to programmers.

Comment: no snail. there's no "clrscr" in Java, you have to dig into executing operating system commands directly for that. Which is deliberate.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a long time ago this function, it might helps you:

```
public void clearScreen() throws IOException{
  String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
  // Clearscreen with 20 newlines (for windows-cmd)
  try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e) {
  }
  if (osName.startsWith("Windows")){
      int i = 0;
      while(i<20){
          System.out.println("\n");
          i++;
      }
  }
  // Clearscreen with escape-sequence (for linux-shell)
  else {
      System.out.println("\u001b[2J");
  }
```

}

The big problem is, that java has no access to the machine, like C etc...

Comment: that actually doesn't "clear the screen", it just scrolls the content out of sight :)
There's no "screen" on the console as such, as it's line oriented rather than page oriented.
You'd need a screen library to enter into exclusive screen mode.

Comment: as i said before:
The big problem is, that java has no access to the machine, like C etc...